# Numpy - Generalize cropping over time dimension

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have a cropping method, that works for `(N, M)` array, and I want it to work for `(T, N, M)` - see below things I've tried and don't work (hint - couldn't get `np.vectorize` to work)

This is the method

```py
def crop(image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Crop a single image
    """
    image_cropped = image[~np.all(image == 0, axis=1)]
    image_cropped = image_cropped[:, ~np.all(image_cropped == 0, axis=0)]

    return image_cropped
```

What I tried

- `np.vectorize(crop)(sequence_of_images)` leads to this error: `numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0`
- `np.apply_along_axis(crop, 0, sequence_of_images)` leads to this error: `numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`

How can I get this to work without using a loop?
(It can be assumed that for each image over time dimension, the size will be equal after cropping, though the images cropping mask is not the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `2D` `image`, the chained indexing could be replicated with an outer mask of rows and cols.

Thus,

```
m1 = ~np.all(image == 0, axis=1)
m2 =  ~np.all(image_cropped == 0, axis=0)

image_cropped = image[m1, :]
image_cropped = image_cropped[:, m2]
```

would be same as :

```
image_cropped = image_cropped[outer_mask(m1, m2)]
```

We will transfer this knowledge to `3D` case. Also, that outer mask for 3D could be easily constructed off the two maks with `keepdims=True` for the `ALL` reductions and finally using elementwise multiplication that takes care of the outer operation.

Thus, we will end up with :

```
mask_0s = image_nd == 0
mask1 = ~np.all(mask_0s, axis=2, keepdims=True)
mask2 = ~np.all(mask_0s, axis=1, keepdims=True)
out = image_nd[mask1 & mask2]
```

Finally to have 3D array output :

```
out = out.reshape(image_nd.shape[0],-1,mask2[0].sum())
```

Comment: Beautiful! Can you elaborate on each step please so I can understand the logic here?

Comment: @bluesummers Added some explanation.